# Sync Products from Opportunity to another object

Tags: apex, process-builder, opportunity, object

I would like to sync the products that are in any Opportunity to appear on another object when the Opportunity is "Closed Won".

I am using this 3rd Party app which is for tracking projects.

I would like a projected created when an Opportunity is "Closed Won" and have the products from the Opportunity copied to the Project.

I have tried process builder but no luck.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: @sfdcfox I was able to get the link of the products copied to the other Object. I want the products to show just like they appear on the Opportunity

Comment: Have you added the related list to the page layout, then?

Comment: @sfdcfox No, I was trying to do that but I can't seem to figure out how. That was my first approach.